# OleDbException was Unhandled - Not a valid file name

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection, oledbconnection

I've tried to establish a connection between my MS Access database and my c# application and I am not understanding why I am getting this error when the filename is correct.

[image]

Any

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sQTDBDataSet.tblEquipment' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tblEquipmentTableAdapter.Fill(this.sQTDBDataSet.tblEquipment);
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Application\Application\bin\Debug\SQTDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();
        checkConnectionLabel.Text = "Connected.";
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: [Oledb, crash if DB path have spaces… C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925369/oledb-crash-if-db-path-have-spaces-c-sharp)

Comment: I've changed the folder from Visual Studio 2015 to VisualStudio2015 and the file path to suit that. However I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\Users\Owner\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\Application\Application\bin\Debug\SQTDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";   Is the connection string I have, without spaces.

Comment: Still getting an error with the above connection, not sure why? :/

Comment: Enclose your path in Double Quote marks